# imap + email parser, all header fields are undefined except last one

Tags: node.js, imap, email-parsing

I am building a simple nodejs script that will fetch my gmail email and will store their data in CouchBase.

The problem is that all the header fields except the last ones are appearing as undefined.

code:

```
var Imap = require('imap'),
    inspect = require('util').inspect,
    MailParser = require("mailparser").MailParser,
    couchbase = require('couchbase'),
    cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(),
    messages = [];

var imap = new Imap({
    user: '***@gmail.com',
    password: '***',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: 993,
    tls: true
});

function openInbox(cb) {
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}

function saveToCouchbase(data){
    var bucket = cluster.openBucket('emails');
    data.forEach(function(doc, index){
        bucket.upsert(index + '', doc, function(err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(doc.subject);
        })
    });
}

function main() {
// using the functions and variables already defined in the first example ...
    imap.once('ready', function() {
        openInbox(function (err, box) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:30', { bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)', 'TEXT'] });
            f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {
                var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
                var parser = new MailParser();
                parser.on('end', function(mailObj){
                    messages.push(mailObj);
                });
                msg.on('body', function (stream, info) {
                    var buffer = '', count = 0;
                    stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
                        parser.write(chunk);
                    });
                });

                f.once('error', function (err) {
                    console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
                });
                f.once('end', function () {
                    console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
                    imap.end();
                });

                msg.once('attributes', function (attrs) {
                    console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
                });
                msg.on('end', function () {
                    console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
                    parser.end();
                });
            });
        });
    });
    imap.once('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    imap.once('end', function() {
        console.log('Connection ended');
        console.log(messages);
        saveToCouchbase(messages);
    });

    imap.connect();
}

main();
```

console log output of 'doc.subject':

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
Your Co-Worker Invited You to Join!
```

One of the messages looks as following:

```
{ text: 'Date: Sun, 05 May 2013 12:07:59 +0300\nSubject: Mentor Graphics -  =?UTF-8?B?15TXqdeZ16o=?=\n =?UTF-8?B?15XXoyDXlNeQ15XXmNeV157XmNeZIA==?=\n =?UTF-8?B?15HXnNeZ16DXp9eT15DXmQ==?=\n =?UTF-8?B?158g15PXqNeaINeY15XXnteZ15LXlQ==?=\n =?UTF-8?B?INei15XXnteTINec15TXodeq15nXmQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?150=?=\nFrom: Tomigo <dontreply@atav.co.il>\nTo: Oleg b<hans.landsberg@gmail.com>\n\n',...}
```

Hence the header an interpreted as text by mistake?.

Comment: node.js isn't my thing, but I can tell you about IMAP: You're trying to get parts of a message and parse that as if it were a complete message. Don't. Make up your mind. Either get the message and parse it, or get the parts and treat them as parts. If you decide for the message, FETCH BODY[]. If you decide for the parts, issue FETCH (ENVELOPE BODYSTRUCTURE) and don't use Mailparser. There are many examples on SO you can copy. Once you've processed BODYSTRUCTRE you can fetch BODY[n], for the appropriate and desirable values of n. BODY[1] is common, BODY[1.1] and [1.2] too.